# Bad formatted expr returning empty string in Tcl

Tags: tcl, expr

This may sound silly. Bear with me. While playing around with `expr`, I came across the following scenario

```
proc badExpr { a b } { 
    return expr $a+$b
}

proc goodExpr { a b } { 
    return [ expr {$a+$b} ]
}

puts "Bad Expression Result : --->[ badExpr 1 3 ]<-----"
puts "Good Expression Result : [ goodExpr 1 3 ]"
```

**Output:**

```
Bad Expression Result : ---><-----
Good Expression Result : 4
```

As you can see, the proc `badExpr` is returning an empty string. Just out of curiosity, I am interested to know why it is returning an empty string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funnily enough, a `badExpr` would be like this:

```
proc badExpr { a b } { 
    return [expr $a+$b]
}
```

What you've *actually* got is is `weirdExpr`:

```
proc badExpr { a b } { 
    return expr $a+$b
}
```

What does this really do? It sets things in the result dictionary. Tcl results should really be considered to be a triple of three things: a result code (a small integer, in this case `0` for OK — `1` would be for a thrown error, and there are few other ones you can usually ignore) a result value (what you normally return) and a result dictionary. The result dictionary is used mainly with errors, to hold things like the stack trace (used to populate the `errorInfo` global variable), the line number on which an error occurred, a computer-readable description of the error (used to populate the `errorCode` global variable), etc., but it can hold any old thing. And you're putting something really odd into it (because that's how `return` works); the system-defined keys all begin with a `-` to make them look like ordinary options (and the dictionary itself is often called the option dictionary).

Let's show this using the two-variable form of `catch` (the second variable catches the dictionary):

```
% proc weirdExpr { a b } { 
    return expr $a+$b
}
% catch {weirdExpr 1 3} p q
0
% puts $p
% puts $q
expr 1+3 -code 0 -level 0
```

Yes, there's a funny entry in there called `expr` whose value is `1+3`…

Comment: Thanks Donal. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

**(1)**
    proc badExpr { a b } { 
        return expr $a+$b
    }

In your badExpr above you are not using the TCL expr command. There expr above is treated just like any other string. If you do want to use the command `expr` you must put it in square brackets. So it should be `return [expr $a + $b]`

The return command returns *one string value* and you can also specify various options. As per the documentation below from http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm the last value is the actual return result.

```
return ?result?
return ?-code code? ?result?
return ?option value ...? ?result?
```

However if you have even number of arbitrary args  it doesn't return anything. I am not sure what's going on under the hood but when you use either -code or option you would have a value parameter associated with it. So it seems it may be treating each pair as option/value or code/value and returning the last unassociated item as the result.

```
#Returns 3
return 1 2 3 4 3

#Returns nothing
return 1 2 3
```

**(2)**
The reason expr {$a+$b} works is because it is the last expression in the proc. I*f a procedure doesn't execute an explicit return, then its return value is the value of the last command executed in the procedure's body.* And it doesn't need to be expr {$a+$b}, it can be expr $a+$b as in your badExpr.

Answer (score 1):

In short, the problem is that you don't have brackets around your invocation of `expr`.

```
return expr $a+$b   ;# no worky
return [expr $a+$b] ;# works (but you should have braces around the arguments)
```

It's not *clearly* documented, but it seems that `return` accepts an arbitrary number of arguments. If the argument list is even-sized, the command returns the empty string. If the number of arguments is odd, it returns the last argument. This is consistent with the documentation: the normal argument list consists of an optional result value preceded by zero or more option name/value pairs. It's still a little unexpected since one would suppose that the option names were constrained to the useful ones.

Oh! And if `return` is the last command in a script and its only argument is a script evaluation (code within brackets), you can always skip the `return` (the byte compiler will eliminate it anyway).

```
proc goodExpr { a b } { 
    return [ expr {$a+$b} ]
}
```

is the same as

```
proc goodExpr { a b } { 
    expr {$a+$b}
}
```

Documentation: [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm), [return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm)